# When dragging a window to another screen, it snaps to the top. How can I stop this?

Tags: macos

Mac OS 10.10.x

As in title.

I find this very annoying and want the OS to stop trying to think what I want to do - especially in this case.

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing this in Mission Control and the app is being assigned to a space? I use multiple displays with my Mac every day and don't experience this, but it could be specific to the application you are using.

Comment: I don'e know.  What are your Mission Control settings.  I try not to use it.  I have set Displays have separate spaces to off and the Dashboard off as well.  The only MC setting that is on is "Group windows by application".

Comment: Try turning on "displays have separate spaces". What application is this behavior happening to? Or is it all applications?